# Kendo ui Sortable send object to function

Tags: angularjs, sorting, kendo-ui

If I want to catch moved object in kendo ui sortable all I can get is just simple `(e)` event in function with all properties... But how to get raw object with its id, name, title,...

```
<ul id="playlist" class="playlist" kendo-sortable k-placeholder="placeholder" k-connect-with="'#playlist2,#hey'"  k-hint="hint" k-change="matt2" k-options="sortableOptions">
<li ng-repeat="obj in listItems2">
    <div class="item"> {{obj.title}} </div>
 </li>
</ul>

$scope.sortableOptions = {        
    end: function(e) {
      var test = {
        name: e.item[0].innerText,
        title: e.item[0].innerText
      };                
    var index = e.newIndex;
    if (index == -1)
    $scope.listItems.push(test);  
      console.log(e);
    }        
  }
```

[Here is the examle on code pen](http://codepen.io/error505/pen/eBvWLW)